# AWS Code Deploy Deployment Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, aws-code-deploy

I have been using AWS Code deploy from the past 3 months. Every thing went nice. And suddenly When I want to deploy code to EC2 servers today. I am getting this strange error (after it is trying to deploy for more than 20 Minutes).

> The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)

I don't understand what happened.I have not messed any thing with AWS at all,I just tried to deploy code as I always do. What could be the reason?

Comment: did you get the answers of this issue, i am facing same, pls help out.

Comment: No, not really. I am just using filezilla for now

Comment: If you visit the console you should be able to see which lifecycle event the instance deployment failed and why it failed. If you still need help around why it failed, do paste the error message without any sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

Before starting the deployment, make sure to check the deployment group to see if there is any healthy instance listed.

Answer (score 1):

**2** potential **reasons** could be possible here :

1. You might have missed to install the **Code Deploy Agent** on your EC2 instance(s) for which the below set of commands will help you to install

> sudo yum update
>
> sudo yum install aws-cli
>
> cd /home/ec2-user
>
> aws s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/install . --region
>   us-east-1
>
> chmod +x ./install
>
> sudo ./install auto

Please make sure above set of commands depend on the platform you are using, if you are using Amazon's Linux AMI its good to go, for other platforms it may vary.

2. There might be error in your **appspec.yml**, if that is the case then you may be able to see that error in which lifecycle event the error is there. To identify that, go to the deployments => select one of the deployments which got failed => go to events => here you will see the error => clicking on that error will display the reason.

If you want to understand in detail how it works, kindly go through my blog [here](https://kddeveops.blogspot.com/2019/03/create-continuous-integration-pipeline.html)

Please let me know if it doesn't fix your problem.